# ffmpeg: concatinating files creates audio artefacts

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to create a video out of multiple short video files. However, the final video always has audio artefacts, where it sounds like a short high pitch or echo at certain times during the audio. All the audio is a text-to-speech generated voice. No music. The artefacts appear sometimes more, sometimes less. But I would obviously prefer to have 0 of it.

My starting point is a long audio file (mono with audio codec "mp3" according to ffprobe). Within that file are a bunch of short pauses of 4-5 seconds. I detect the silences and create individual audio files from there. Afterwards I create an mp4 file with this audio and a still image. Up to this point, the audio is perfectly fine and sounds the exact same as in the original file.

After this I want to create the final video: each of the individual parts added into one long video. There is a transition between each file to mark the changing of image and audio. But even when skipping the transition and simply adding all of these clips that were generated the same way together, the artefacts are still present.

The commands I use to create the different files.

Create individual audio files:
`.\ffmpeg.exe -y -hide_banner -i TTSAudio.mp3 -ss 359.944 -to 372.02479 -c copy partXY.mp3`

Create individual video files by using a .png file as the video stream and the partXY.mp3 as the audio stream:
`.\ffmpeg.exe -y -hide_banner -framerate 30 -loop 1 -i XY_full.png -i partXY.mp3 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -shortest partXY.mp4`

For concatenating the files:
`.\ffmpeg.exe -y -hide_banner -i part000.mp4 -i part001.mp4 -i part002.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a copy final_video.mp4`

I've tried a lot of different things and codecs for the audio, without any luck. I use h265, as using h264 was causing weird video artefacts after uploading the file to YouTube.
I have tried reencoding, instead of copying (-c:a copy) at various stages, especially the final video. All without any luck.
I've used the different concatenation where you provide a list of files, which created a whole different set of problems.

I've managed to filter the artefacts out by using -af "lowpass=f=2800", but that changes the voice a lot. I was also not able to notice the pitch visually when opening the audio in audacity, for example.

Example:
https://soundcloud.com/thelml/sets/ffmpeg-audio-artefacts/s-LNr6UaMPgz9?si=f7b30e1e64bf4333ad055fa1fe21e9ec
Due to the files being so short, I seem to have to sometimes have to replay the bugged file to hear the artefact.

So my question is: how do I fix this, without using a lowpass that basically changes the whole voice?

Comment: Looking at the spectrogram in Praat, your "bugged" signal has been lowpassed to 8 kHz. Otherwise, I don't see any artifact that you speak of. There is a short tone (like behavior) between 0.43 and 0.48s around 11.3 kHz, which is the cutoff of the original audio's upper frequency content. If `bugged` was created by `-c:a copy` something is wrong in your toolchain.

Comment: If audio and video streams are not related (i.e., speaker's lips aren't visible in the video), have you considered concatenating them separately?

Comment: I just realised, that the ```-c:a copy``` in the last statement (the concatenation) doesn't seem to work, due to the complex filters. Maybe that has something to do with it.
No, I haven't tried to concatenate the video and audio streams separately and then merging them. I'll give that a try, thank you for the idea.